# How should I import AppModuleNgFactory to bootstrap an aot build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Im trying to setup a basic angular app created using angular-cli to be compiled using aot. Its hard to figure out what the main.ts file should look like in order to bootstrap the app since angular-cli hides the tsconfig.json file and I can not find relevant documentation describing how to do this. Can someone help me set this up correctly?

My `ng version` is

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.25.5                                                                  │127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2017 12:09:31] "GET /main.bundle.map HTTP/1.1" 200     -
node: 7.4.0                                                                               │^C
os: linux x64                                                                             │Keyboard interrupt received, exiting.
@angular/common: 2.4.3                                                                    │joi ~/workspace/angular2/testing/dist $ cd ..
@angular/compiler: 2.4.3                                                                  │joi ~/workspace/angular2/testing $ cd dis
@angular/core: 2.4.3                                                                      │-bash: cd: dis: No such file or directory
@angular/forms: 2.4.3                                                                     │joi ~/workspace/angular2/testing $ cd dist
@angular/http: 2.4.3                                                                      │-bash: cd: dist: No such file or directory
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.3                                                          │joi ~/workspace/angular2/testing $ cd dist
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.3                                                  │joi ~/workspace/angular2/testing/dist $ ls
@angular/router: 3.4.3                                                                    │assets       inline.bundle.js   main.bundle.map    vendor.bundle.js
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.3
```

The package.json file is:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                
  "name": "testing",                                                                                                                                                             
  "version": "0.0.0",                                                                                                                                                            
  "license": "MIT",                                                                                                                                                              
  "angular-cli": {},                                                                                                                                                             
  "scripts": {                                                                                                                                                                   
    "ng": "ng",                                                                                                                                                                  
    "start": "ng serve",                                                                                                                                                         
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --type-check && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --type-check",                                
    "test": "ng test",                                                                                                                                                           
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",                                                                                                       
    "e2e": "protractor"                                                                                                                                                          
  },                                                                                                                                                                             
  "private": true,                                                                                                                                                               
  "dependencies": {                                                                                                                                                              
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",                                                                                                                                                 
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",                                                                                                                                               
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",                                                                                                                                                   
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",                                                                                                                                                  
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",                                                                                                                                                   
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",                                                                                                                                       
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",                                                                                                                               
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",                                                                                                                                                 
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",                                                                                                                                                         
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",                                                                                                                                                            
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",                                                                                                                                                      
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"                                                                                                                                                          
  },                                                                                                                                                                             
  "devDependencies": {                                                                                                                                                           
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",                                                                                                                                           
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",                                                                                                                                                  
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",                                                                                                                                                    
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.25.5",                                                                                                                                            
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",                                                                                                                                                
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",                                                                                                                                                     
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",                                                                                                                                            
    "karma": "1.2.0",                                                                                                                                                            
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",                                                                                                                                           
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",                                                                                                                                                       
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",                                                                                                                                                   
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",                                                                                                                                            
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",                                                                                                                                                     
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",                                                                                                                                                          
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",                                                                                                                                                          
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"                                                                                                                                                       
  }                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

The main.ts file currently looks like this:

```
import './polyfills.ts';                                                                                                                         
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';                                                                                                                      
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app/app.module.ngfactory';                                                                                                                     
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your project:

```
ng new super-project
```

build your project:

```
ng build
```

build your project with AoT:

```
ng build --aot
```

**CELEBRATE!!!**

No extra configuration is needed on your part.

Comment: Im looking for help with the bootstrapping step. I.e. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#bootstrap

So my question is: what goes into the main.ts to bootstrap the app

Comment: The CLI build process replaces the JIT bootstrapping code you see with AOT compatible code during the build process, so if you're using the CLI and it's build process, you do not need to do anything.

Comment: Oh. That means I have been banging my had against the table for no reason? That's great and a bit annoying at the same time...

Comment: Im confused. The filesize with aot compilation are larger than without. Any idea what is going on there?

Comment: With aot: dist/vendor.bundle.js: 2.4M, dist/main.bundle.js: 2.5M, dist/inline.bundle.js: 8.0K, Total: 4.9M

Without aot: dist/vendor.bundle.js: 3.8M, dist/main.bundle.js: 540K, dist/inline.bundle.js: 8.0K, Total: 4.3M

Comment: With the --prod flag its the same: `ng build --prod` yields a 308K total and `ng build --aot --prod` yields 320K

Comment: Sorry you were banging your head... it really is that easy. As for the bundle sizes, it's being looked at to make the output as small as possible.

Comment: How does that work though? Lets say I have a more complex main.ts file. How does angular-cli make sure to replace the bootstrapping code correctly? That seems magical.

Comment: We use something called the Abstract Syntax Tree which is a deep understanding of the code which we use to find the import and usage for replacement during build. This is made available via the TypeScript language services.